# Calculation of $σ_u σ_u$ and $σ_u σ_v$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

[image]

Accourding to the info which I posted, how can I calculate $σ_u σ_u=\vert\vert σ_u\vert\vert^2$ and  $σ_u σ_v$ I am stuck with there. Please show me. Thanks.

Comment: This is just the inner product of two vectors.

Comment: I forget how to do this. Please can you show one of them. Dear @ZhenLin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example:

$$\sigma_u\cdot\sigma_v:=2\cosh u\cosh v\sinh u\sinh v$$

If you really meant the dot product you jsut take the sum of coordinatewise product of the vectors' entries.

Comment: That is, for example, let $σ_u= ai+bj+ck$ and $σ_v=di+fj+ek$ Then $σ_uσ_v=a.d i+ bf j+ ce k$ is this right? Its result is not important for me. The way to get it is important.

Comment: No. The inner product of two vectors is always a scalar (number in the definition field), so in your example $$\sigma_u\cdot\sigma_v=ad+bf+ce$$

Comment: I understand thanks. Well, I have one more question. $\cosh^2 u =1+\sinh ^2 u$ is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can check it right away writing down the exponential defintiions of $\;\cosh\,,\,\sinh\;$

Comment: Okay your answers help me so much:) thanks a lot:)